# About Ethereum Private Blockchain

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I want to transfer some data among two computers by using ethereum private blockchain. Can someone help me with this? Step by step guidance will be more helpful.

Comment: I would like to know what inspired you to do this, according to me this is not the ideal use-case for Blockchain tech.

Comment: Actually this is for my project.

Comment: Can't you write a simple mechanism to transfer data i.e. something using Java main method. rather than using ethereum blockchain ?

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

on a private testnet you may simply put in data in your transaction and send it to and fro between the nodes with an event listening in for new transactions . Since youre on a private net ,ether is not an issue. you could also make the difficulty static so as to increase the transaction speed.

Alternatively you may try your luck with whisper which is a new protocol to talk between nodes . https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Whisper

Answer (score -1):

I think quorum provides what you are looking for: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum

It's an open source private blockchain implementation based on ethereum.